# Adding a rigid container to show logs on streamlit application?

Tags: streamlit

I built a multi page streamlit application that has logs.
I want to define a rigid place that will show these logs.
If I use st.info for example it just adds that message after the last component (sometimes it is not very convenient to see that).
Is there a way to define a place to be dedicated to getting these messages or other workaround?

Thanks!

Tried to add st.info but it adds them on different locations instead of one place.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `st.cotainer()`. This method will let you display content at any place of your choice. All you have to do is to create a place holder which you can populate it with content later. If this did not help, you will have to make your question more clear.

```py
import streamlit as st

# Display logs here
logs_container =  st.container()

st.write("Some content")
st.write("More content")

log_data = "I am assigned to the logs container and I display only log content"
logs_container.info(log_data)

logs_container.info("I also display some logs...")
```

---

[image]

Comment: What I think you did is exactly what I want, its just that I want it to be in the bottom of my screen. Meaning the user will see the logs regardless if he scrolls up or down but they will be in the bottom part of the screen (like a strip that is dedicated to the logs)

Comment: You definitely need a css rule to accomplish that,  by using devtools through inspection to identify the div class in order to be able to modify it, you will have to set `position: fixed` and also set `z-index: 1000`. That could be done with the help of `st.markdown()`